# Mouse only works in one Linux Mint program at one time

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, mouse

I've recently installed Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon, but I am having problems with my Logitech MK710 wireless desktop mouse. Although it and the keyboard have been detected, the mouse only functions in one program at any time.

For example, if I open Firefox and then the terminal, if I Ctrl+Tab back to Firefox the mouse is no longer responsive within the browser. This continues until I exit the terminal, when mouse functionality is restored in Firefox.

The mouse works without fail in Windows 10 so I assume it is a driver issue of some form. However, I am unsure what drivers I should be searching for (if any exist), so any advice would be most appreciated.